# How to call a function when a tab is opened in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

In my expo app, I want to automatically call a function when the tab is initially opened / navigated to for the first time. Is this possible? All I can find is using onPress to call functions.

Comment: Use `componentDidMount()` in first of tab's screen?

Comment: @高鵬翔 sorry I should say I'm using function components. Is there a way of using componentDidMount with a function component?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) similar to componentDidMount ?

Comment: @高鵬翔 I'll take a look thank you